# Publisher to HTML conversion issues?

Tags: html, microsoft-publisher

my brother is trying to put together a emailer for a organization, and neither of us are good at html and we have to upload a .pub file to a website that only accepts HTML, is there a way i can convert the publisher file to html without losing the formatting in the original document?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can export publisher documents in HTML format:

Publish HTML

This selection enables you to publish your publication as a Web page.

Click the File tab.

Choose Save & Send and selectPublish HTML.

Under Publish HTML, you can choose to save in one of two formats:

Web Page (HTML): This will save your publication as an HTML document, and create a folder containing supporting files such as images and sounds that appear on the page.

Single File Web Page (MHTML): This option creates a single MHT document with the supporting files embedded.

Click Publish HTML, and in theSave Asdialog select a location and enter a file name.

(from https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Save-and-send-Publications-9b06fc49-0d11-453e-8b80-e1bd2124b87c#__toc298830409)